# Rails: save scraped data to seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping

As I'm trying to fetch data and have the scraped data saved to the database under seeds.rb, I realized the same data would't overwrite itself. And as a result I got multiple repetitive data in the database.

**The goal is to update the existing data with new info instead of creating new ones.**

Here's how I fetch the data:

**seed.rb**

```rb
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'
require 'json'

url = URI("https://google-flights-search.p.rapidapi.com/search?departure_airport_code=HND&arrival_airport_code=TPE&departure_date=2022-02-17&flight_class=Economy")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.read_timeout = 300
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
request["x-rapidapi-host"] = ENV["x-rapidapi-host"]
request["x-rapidapi-key"] = ENV["x-rapidapi-key"]

response = http.request(request)
dep_hash = JSON.parse(response.read_body)
```

I planned to only show the cheapest flight and save it to the database, and expected every time I run `rails db:seed` the data would be updated and overwritten. (as I set the ticket_id to be the same)

```rb
dep_flight_data = dep_hash["flights"]
tempPrice = 10000
depHash= {}
for flight in dep_flight_data
  if flight["price"]< tempPrice
  tempPrice = flight["price"]
  depHash = flight
  end
end
dep_ticket_id = (depHash["departure_airport_code"]+depHash["arrival_airport_code"]+ depHash["departure_date"]).split('/').join

Ticket.create(
  ticket_id: dep_ticket_id,
  departure: depHash["departure_airport_code"],
  arrival: depHash["arrival_airport_code"],
  departure_date: depHash["departure_date"],
  ticket_amount: (depHash["price"]*28)
)
```

current seed data as below:
[image]

Is there any way I can update the seeds file correctly?
Any guides are much appreciated!

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of contexts which makes it very hard to understand? Can you please elaborate on where and how you scraped data? How do you store it in your database? How do your seed files look like? And why do you import the seed file multiple times?

Comment: @spickermann thanks for the reply. I scraped data by hitting rapid API's google flights API. And I intend to test out the whenever gem and ransack gem hence I want to import some data repeatedly. Please kindly revisit the edited question. Any feedbacks are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just adding all found tickets into the database you need to check if a similar ticket already exists before creating a new one.

This can be done by changing

```
Ticket.create(
  ticket_id: dep_ticket_id,
  departure: depHash["departure_airport_code"],
  arrival: depHash["arrival_airport_code"],
  departure_date: depHash["departure_date"],
  ticket_amount: (depHash["price"]*28)
)
```

to

```
Ticket
  .create_with(
    departure: depHash["departure_airport_code"],
    arrival: depHash["arrival_airport_code"],
    departure_date: depHash["departure_date"],
    ticket_amount: (depHash["price"]*28)
  )
  .find_or_create_by(ticket_id: dep_ticket_id)
```

See [docs for `find_or_create_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback